# how i can download Adobe AIR bundled runtime installer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I am trying to package air runtime and air application in a native installer.
i googled a lot on how to achive the same. i found this link http://kuriakosejacobthomas.blogspot.com/2009/10/bundled-deployment-of-adobe-air_13.html

which says u need **' AIR bundled runtime installer'**   to package air runtime with air application.

But havn't found any air bundled runtime installer. from where i can download 'AIR bundled runtime installer' ?

OR suggest any alternative way to package the air runtime with air application except badge from web page.

I am trying to create AIR native installer bundled with AIR runtime for windows, Mac and Linux operating system??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

The first is to sign up for the [AIR Redistribution program](http://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html).  This will give you access and permission to bundle and distribute the AIR runtime into your own installer.

The second is to use AIR 3 and [Captive Runtime](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader) feature which will bundle the runtime into your app.

Comment: @Flextras: Thanks for the link. An example(i mean adt command line syntax) using the Captive Runtime to create native installer with AIR runtime will be more helpful.

Comment: @gannesh The link I provided includes the command line argument to create a captive runtime on Android: "-target apk-captive-runtime" .  Googling around includes more information and tutorials: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/

Comment: -target apk-captive-runtime is for android and they don't have fully explained command line argument for desktop. i am looking for the desktop applications.

Comment: i hv googled lots pf pages but none of them expalining exact command line argument for desktop.

Comment: Does this help?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html  -target bundle